# Detect assembly overflow?

Tags: assembly, overflow

I'm writing an assembly program that calculates Fibonacci numbers, but I need to find a way to detect for overflow when the numbers get too large. My current code is:

```
.file   "fib.c"
.text
.globl fib
    .type   fib, @function
fib:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je .end
    cmpl $1, %eax
    je .end

    pushl %edx

    subl $1, %eax
    push %eax
    call fib
    popl %ebx
    movl %eax, %edx

    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    subl $2, %eax
    push %eax
    call fib
    popl %ebx
    addl %edx, %eax
    jo .overflow
    popl %edx

.end:
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
.overflow:
    movl $-1, %eax
    ret
```

I thought I would be able to just use the jo test to see if there was an overflow (Around line 25), but I get a segmentation fault when I enter a number that should overflow.

Any thoughts how I can do this correctly? (BTW, running on a 32 bit machine if that matters)

Thanks,
Mike

**EDIT:**
For anyone who is interested, here is the working version. I wasn't clearing the stack and I wasn't checking for overflow on the movl after the first computation.

```
.file "fib.c"
.text
.globl fib
    .type   fib, @function
fib:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je .end
    cmpl $1, %eax
    je .end

    pushl %edx  

    subl $1, %eax
    pushl %eax
    call fib
    popl %ebx
    movl %eax, %edx
    jo .overflow

    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    subl $2, %eax
    pushl %eax
    call fib
    popl %ebx
    addl %edx, %eax
    jo .overflow
    popl %edx

.end:
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
.overflow:
    movl $-1, %eax
    movl $-1, %edx
    jmp .end
```

Comment: You posted code that works instead of the code you have a problem with.  Not a good idea.  Fix the snippet and show *exactly* where the fault occurs.

Comment: That code actually did cause a segmentation fault because I didn't do an overflow check on "movl %eax, %edx". I did however fix it and I am editing now with working code.

Comment: Mike, without checking, I don't believe MOV instructions set or reset any flags. I don't code in assembly much any more though, so I could very well be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you're using recursion, I'd suspect the *stack* is what is overflowing, causing your segfault.

---

on second thought, when you hit numeric overflow, you 'ret' without cleaning up your stack first. jump to '.end' instead:

```
.overflow:
    movl $-1, %eax
    jmp .end
```

Comment: time for me to get some sleep, I can't think clearly. I believe the answer is correct as of my last edit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of this will fix your problem, but there are a couple of typos here where you say push instead of pushl.